problem with AMR ++ pipeline using both "conda" and "singularity" profiles
Hi I am having problem with  AMR ++ pipeline
https://www.meglab.org/amrplusplus/
I tried both in cluster and in my local using both "conda" and "singularity" profiles...but no luck.
First using conda profile... for a single paired files processed with kneaddata.
(base) % 

    ./nextflow run /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/main_AMR++.nf -profile conda  --reads “PATH/modified_05_02_24_A_S1_L001_R1_001_kneaddata_paired_{1,2}.fastq” --output PATH/AMR_out -w /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/AMR_working  --pipeline resistome


 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.10.0

Launching `/Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/main_AMR++.nf` [focused_brahmagupta] DSL2 - revision: 8426bc09be

 A M R + +    N F   P I P E L I N E
 ===================================
 Reads being analyzed : “PATH/modified_05_02_24_A_S1_L001_R1_001_kneaddata_paired_1.fastq”
 With the pipeline    : resistome
 Output folder        : PATH/AMR_out
 
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
===================================
Running the resistome subworkflow
===================================
        
Creating env using mamba: /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env.yaml [cache /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env-33183b665857020ee714d35a2eb5166c]
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'FASTQ_RESISTOME_WF:bwa_align (1)'

Caused by:
  Failed to create Conda environment
    command: mamba env create --prefix /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env-33183b665857020ee714d35a2eb5166c --file /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envsCreating env using mamba: /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env.yaml [cache /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env-33183b665857020ee714d35a2eb5166c]
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'FASTQ_RESISTOME_WF:bwa_align (1)'

Caused by:
  Failed to create Conda environment
    command: mamba env create --prefix /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env-33183b665857020ee714d35a2eb5166c --file /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/AMR++_env.yaml
    status : 127
    message:
      bash: mamba: command not found



 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details

I have also tried this with Singularity profile...error bellow.
    ./nextflow run /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/main_AMR++.nf -profile singularity  --reads “PATH/modified_05_02_24_A_S1_L001_R1_001_kneaddata_paired_{1,2}.fastq” --output PATH/AMR_out -w PATH/AMR_working  --pipeline resistome


 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.10.0

Launching `/Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/main_AMR++.nf` [insane_descartes] DSL2 - revision: 8426bc09be

 A M R + +    N F   P I P E L I N E
 ===================================
 Reads being analyzed : “PATH/modified_05_02_24_A_S1_L001_R1_001_kneaddata_paired_1.fastq”
 With the pipeline    : resistome
 Output folder        : PATH/AMR_out
 
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
WARN: Include with `addParams()` is deprecated -- pass params as a workflow or process input instead
===================================
Running the resistome subworkflow
===================================
        
Pulling Singularity image docker://enriquedoster/amrplusplus:latest [cache /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/enriquedoster-amrplusplus-latest.img]
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'FASTQ_RESISTOME_WF:build_dependencies'

Caused by:
  Failed to pull singularity image
    command: singularity pull  --name enriquedoster-amrplusplus-latest.img.pulling.1730819087601 docker://enriquedoster/amrplusplus:latest > /dev/null
Pulling Singularity image docker://enriquedoster/amrplusplus:latest [cache /Users/medsmit/AMR/AMRplusplus/envs/enriquedoster-amrplusplus-latest.img]
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'FASTQ_RESISTOME_WF:build_dependencies'

Caused by:
  Failed to pull singularity image
    command: singularity pull  --name enriquedoster-amrplusplus-latest.img.pulling.1730819087601 docker://enriquedoster/amrplusplus:latest > /dev/null
    status : 127
    hint   : Try and increase singularity.pullTimeout in the config (current is "20m")
    message:
      bash: singularity: command not found



 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
(base) medsmit@UOL-L-RKW9GGWWJ7 AMR % 

Any help will be greatly approciated.
